# Google Data Studio Scoreboard SUM calculation

Tags: looker-studio

I have my data on Excel and I uploaded in Google Sheets so I can use Google Data Studio, everything in Data Studio so far working good, but I am having trouble in a case.

Few of my fields in Data source have values in numbers from 1 to 1000+ and I chose cell formatting in excel as Numbers with 1000 Separator(,).
In Data Studio data source I changed same field with "Number" but when I try to create a simple Scoreboard on Data Studio, it seems like it's only doing [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) with values lower than 1000, meaning any value with 1000 or above are being skipped.

I can feel this is because of separator(,) which is troubling and I can use:

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE)
```

but I want to know that why it's making trouble, even after choosing correct Cell Format?

Sample Data Link: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/abafc2cb-9033-4851-9f72-02896a91384c

Answer (score 0):

The field `ITEM SUPPLIED` is a text field and contains numbers formated as text. However, there is a  1000 separator (`,`) in the text.

Therefore, every `,` in the field has to be removed. This can be done by the `REPLACE` function. Then the `CAST` converts the text to a number.

```
CAST(REPLACE(ITEM SUPPLIED, ",", "") AS number )
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, the separator (,) works as Number in Excel's Format Cell not for Text? I am not convinced why cell format Number is being detected as Text in Data Studio? And one more thing, Country control list is working for both Item Supplied & Item Received but Month control is not working for both, why? (Note: I have duplicated Date field in Source and Changed it to Month, so I can view Monthly report by single click)

Comment: I somehow manage to fix Month Control issue as I was doing wrong by duplicating Date field, I just had to use date field and change it to Month in control properties. But the real issue regarding number with separator is being detect as text in Google Sheets or Data Studio.